# Reading Excel File Cell value as HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, xlsx

I want to read formatted cell value as HTML for rendering it on webpage in Angular.
is their any way to do that in angular.

For eg. I've Name in excel cell which is formated as bold, how can i read it as **Name** in angular and render it on webpage.

I searched for some libraries but i didn't find any promising information.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion if that works for you. You can actually convert an excel sheet to a HTML one. The conversion is not based on javascript, you have to do it manually on excel.

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3593-excel-convert-cells-to-html-table.html

However, if you have a big excel file you first need to have a good HTML editor. You need to make some changes to the converted HTML file.And, In angular you can use this HTML by first sanitizing it and using innerHtml in your template.